# Unity UI GetComponent

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am making a dialog system, so I created a prefab with: the main character portrait (image), NPC portrait (image), the image where text will appear and the last one is the text. In my script I pass this prefab and I save it in a variable called dialog_panel. Once I created the prefab in code, I want to change the text for the first phrase is going to say my NPC. But it crashes:

> "GetComponent requires that the requested component 'TextElement' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
>   UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent[T] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/GameObject.bindings.cs:28)
>   Interactivity.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Interactivity.cs:74)"

I tried everyting to get the component text of my UI text/label, but it's impossible D:. My unity version is: 2019.3.0.a5

Here is my code, commented things give me the same error:

```
dialog_panel = Instantiate(copy_panel);
dialog_panel.transform.SetParent(FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform, false);
dialog_panel.transform.position = new Vector3(512, 99, dialog_panel.transform.position.z);
//dialog_panel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Label>().text = "HOLAA";
/*GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("NPCText");
TextElement instruction = obj.GetComponent<TextElement>();
instruction.text = "HI";
//obj.GetComponent<TextElement>().text = "HI";*/
// dialog_panel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Label>().text = "HI"; 
dialog_panel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<TextElement>().text = "HI";
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure you are looking for a [`TextElement`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Experimental.UIElements.TextElement.html) and not rather simply a [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component?

Comment: Amazing, it works now! Really thanks